# Android JDBC MySQL get tables by Database

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I got through some tutorials, but all of them are very simple an can not be used in my solution.

I have connection to a database via JDBC MySQL.

```
public class ConnCore extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

Activity activity;
    Context context;
    public ConnCore(Context context, Activity currActivity) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        this.activity = currActivity;
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


        try{Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");}
        catch(Exception e){
           DataStore.DataStoreClass.connExc = e;
            return false;}


        try{

          DataStore.DataStoreClass.mysqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(DataStore.DataStoreClass.connectionString);

            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            DataStore.DataStoreClass.connExc = e;
            return false;
        }





    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Boolean b) {


         if(b == true) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DBList.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);



        } else {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage(DataStore.DataStoreClass.connExc.toString());
            alertDialog.show();

        }
}
```

This will do in connection with this string:

```
static String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3306?user=root&password=test&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";
```

If connected succesfully, it starts new activity DBList, which starts new AsyncTask to get Databases.
AsyncTask looks like this:

```
public class GetDBList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    Activity activity;
    Context context;
    public GetDBList(Context context, Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){


        Statement stmt = null;
        String query = "SHOW DATABASES";
        DataStore.DataStoreClass.DBResponse = new ArrayList<String>();



        try {
            DatabaseMetaData meta = DataStore.DataStoreClass.mysqlConn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet res = meta.getCatalogs();
            while (res.next()) {
                DataStore.DataStoreClass.DBResponse.add(res.getString("TABLE_CAT"));

            }
            res.close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (SQLException e){

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage(e.toString());
            alertDialog.show();
            return false;
        }





    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean b){
       if(b) {
           ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DataStore.DataStoreClass.DBResponse){
               @Override
               public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                   View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                   TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                   text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                   return view;
               }
           };
           ListView lv = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.db_lv);
           lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

           lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {


                   DataStore.DataStoreClass.currentDB = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                   Toast.makeText(context, DataStore.DataStoreClass.currentDB,
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
                   alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                   alertDialog.setMessage(DataStore.DataStoreClass.connExc.toString());
                   alertDialog.show();

               }
           });

       }


    }
}
```

Up to this point, everything works just fine, I can get the ListView with databases.

And now. Every List_Item has onClickListener.
How I can pass the String value (containing name of database) to my existing connection to get its tables?

Every tutorial is already with name of database. I am trying to create an universal DB client, so you actually dont know, what databases are on server.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName +  "/" + schema;
```

And I don't want to close previous connection and make a new one directly to the database

So is it somehow possible to "edit"

```
(static Connection mysqlConn;)
DataStore.DataStoreClass.mysqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(DataStore.DataStoreClass.connectionString);
```

somehow ... or any other way?

Thank you.

Comment: First off - its okay for a connection to access multiple databases. As long as the user has oermissions on them thats okay.

Comment: @Jan I think, you didnt get the point. I am able to list databases. Then, I need to select one from the list returned, and gets its table list. My problem is, how to do it, when all tutorials are counting with "I know the database name when creating the connection" - and that I dont know. I need to select the database from the list, I cannot hardcore it to solution. I need to edit just one database at time

Comment: "Show tables from " + dbname

Comment: Sorry - was on mobile. In more words: you can list tables, read data and so on even if you're not connected to that database through the connect string. You could even execute "use "+dbname as sql thus changing the default db for your active connection.

Comment: You can connect to the database without database name **String url="jdbc:mysql://{hostname}:{port}"** and when you query you have to append the {dbname} for example **select * from dbname.dbtable**

Comment: "show databases" command will give the list dbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your point correctly, you would like to connect to the database but, you do not know the database name in advance. Correct?

If above is true, then you can connect to the database without having to provide the database name. Just supply the hostname and port to the `DriverManager` as shown below:

```
String url="jdbc:mysql://{hostname}:{port}"
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Now that you have a valid `Connection` you need to find out what databases are there. You already know that but, I will provide an example anyway just so I cover everything. Create a `java.sql.Statement` using the above `java.sql.Connection` object as shown  below:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String SQL = "SHOW DATABASES";
```

Run the above `SQL` statement to get a list of database names as follow:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
```

Iterate through the returned list of database names and add those that matter to a list skipping the system and other internal databases. See below:

```
List<String> dbNames = new ArrayList<String>(); 

while (rs.next()) {
    // Retrieve by column name
    String name = rs.getString("Database");
    if(!name.equals("information_schema") && !name.equals("mysql") && !name.equals("performance_schema") && !name.equals("sys")) {
        dbNames.add(name); 
    }
}
```

Assuming that I only have `db1`, `db2` and `db3` in my database, then the list will contain the following when printed

```
[db1, db2, db3]
```

Now I would like to retrieve a list of tables for each of the above databases. I have manually created table `t1 and t2 in db1` database, `x1 and x2 in db2` database, `z1 and z2 in db3` database, see how I iterator through the database tables in different ways below:

**Method 1:** You can use the [setCatalog(String dbname)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog(java.lang.String)) method of `java.sql.Connection` class in order to set a database name to `Connection` object. This acts like `USE {dbname}` sql command. See the example below

```
for(int i = 0; i < dbNames.size(); i++) {
    //here I am setting the dbname in connection obj
    conn.setCatalog(dbNames.get(i));
    //then I am creating a new Statement
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    sql = "SHOW TABLES";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1) 
           + " is a table in " + dbNames.get(i) + " database.");
    }
}
```

**Method 2:** In this method, you can avoid using `java.sql.Connection` class's `setCatalog(String dbname)` method by changing the SQL command to as follow:

```
sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM " + dbNames.get(i);
```

Both methods should give you the same output as shown below:

```
[db1, db2, db3]
t1 is a table in db1 database.
t2 is a table in db1 database.
x1 is a table in db2 database.
x2 is a table in db2 database.
z1 is a table in db3 database.
z2 is a table in db3 database.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try today. Method 1 seems to be OK, as far as I can tell just like looking at code, something very similar I have thought of.. Method 2 is not usable for me, because from list of tables, I will need to show all rows of table, from all rows of that table I will need to edit a row, and so on... so I need to "set a pointer" into the database for a further work.

Comment: @Zorak you are welcome. If this answer helped resolve your issue then you have the option to mark it as **accepted**

Comment: Sorry for waiting. Tried to implement method1 and it is working!!!! Thank you very much for your time spent to help me. Really appreciate it. Have a nice time :)